# Python function checking for common elements using function

Tags: python

The goal is to take two lists see if any elements match and if they do add 1 to count every time. The first list is a list of 5 elements and the second is user input. It doesn't work , what am I doing wrong? It has to be done using a function please help.

```
userask = input("Enter a few numbers to try win the lotto:      ")


def count_correct(list1,list2):


    count = 0
    for r in list2:
        if list1 in list2:
                count += 1

    return count
```

Comment: I'm sure some code of yours is missing. Hint: create `set` objects from the items and use intersection on them to get the common elements, then `len` to count them

Comment: We were told we aren't allowed to use those for this question we need to use a function

Answer (score 1):

You first need to split the numbers by spaces (as you wish) and turn into a list:

```
userask = input("Enter a few numbers to try win the lotto:      ")
userlist = userask.split()
```

Then you can do it either using a set like so:

```
result = len(set(list1) & set(userlist))
```

Where only the non-duplicate common ones will be counted or fix your `for` loop like so:

```
def count_correct(list1,list2):

    count = 0
    for r in list2:
        if r in list1:
            count += 1

    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement your count function, you can use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) with a [*generator expression*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

```
def count_correct(list1, list2):
     # each True in the generator expression is coerced to int value 1
     return sum(i in list1 for i in list2)
```

**Note** that using *sets* will eliminate duplicates in your lists, if any, which will give incorrect results.

---

To capture your list of inputs you can do:

```
userask = input("Enter a few numbers to try win the lotto (separated by spaces):      ")

list1  = map(int, userask.split())
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code is incomplete here. But I think this change should help you.

Don't use `if list1 in list2:`, use `if r in list2:`